# Передача переменной из js в php

Tags: php, javascript

Есть форма с отправкой данных в php и получение результата обратно.

```
<form id="call" action="">
<input type="text" name="name"></div>
<input type="submit" class="" value="Отправить">
</form>
<div id="calls"/>
```

call.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
    $("#call").submit(function()
    {
        var str = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "call.php",
            data: str,
            success: function(msg)
            {
                elm = document.getElementById('calls');
                elm.innerHTML = msg;
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

call.php

```
$call = 1;
echo 'Тут текст';
```

Как в js сделать проверку на $call?.

Comment: что значит проверку на $call?

Comment: В php $call равен 1, в js делаем проверку на значение $call и если $call равен 1, то допустим показываем див `$("#test").fadeIn;` Форма с именем просто для примера. Нужно в самом js сделать проверку на значение переменной $call

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript
а этот ответ вам чем не подходил?
там уйма вариантов как добраться из js в переменные из php кода

Comment: @Олександр К сожалению я плохо владею Английским, очень сложно разобраться. Если я правильно смотрел, то там js и php находятся в одном файле

Comment: @nicolaa Проверьте код, я сделал - все работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Php:

```
if($call == 1)
{
 echo "call = 1";
}
```

Jquery

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
    $("#call").submit(function(e)
    {
        var str = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "call.php",
            data: str,
            success: function(data)
            {
                elm = document.getElementById('calls');
                var regex = /call = (\d)/g;
                m = regex.exec(data)
                if(m[1] == 1)
                {
                    console.log("yes");
                  $("#test").fadeIn();  
                }
                elm.innerHTML = data;
            }
        })

    return false;
    });

   });
```

Comment: Работает, но в моем случаи php выводит еще рандомный текст

Comment: можете дать пример текста

Comment: Вот `echo '<img src="'.$response->error->captcha_img.'" alt="Captcha">';

    echo '<form method="post">';
    echo '<input type="text" name="captcha_key" required>';                           
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="captcha_sid" value="'.$response->error->captcha_sid.'">';
    echo '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Отправить</button>';
    echo '</form>';`   `$response->error->captcha_img` и `$response->error->captcha_sid` рандомные.     s

Comment: зачем в этом файле капча? не совсем понимаю логику. обьянисте плиз

Comment: Весь код в вопросе это просто пример, чтобы проще было понять, что мне нужно. А так это скрипт отправки постов в группу вконтакте через api [Вот пример кода](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/608489/Работа-с-captcha-vk-api) только отправка формы сделана через js

Comment: можно через регулярное вырожение достать `call = 1` из файла php, посмотрите пример кода в ответе

Answer (score 0):

Грубо говоря на СО много есть ответов на вопрос, вас интерессующий, я просто кину вам ссылок, в которых вы можете подсмотреть варианты для вашего конкретного решения
[смотрим тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript) ,
[тут также](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287357/access-php-variable-in-javascript) и
[ну и тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808108/how-to-access-php-variables-in-javascript-or-jquery-rather-than-php-echo-vari)

почему в одном же?
одно из елементранийшех там решений, это присвоить ваш $foo в ХТМЛ класс какому-то значению а-ля data-value и из вашего файла js уже по цепочке получить нужные вам данные.

Comment: То есть в php `echo '<span id="res" data-variable="test"></span>'; ` в js делать проверку `document.getElementById("res").getAttribute("data-variable");`? Проблема в том, что вся информация, который передает php по сути не видимая, зайдя в Исходный код видно, что div calls в который выводиться текст `Тут текст` из php - пустой, хотя на сайте текст виден. Когда я в php вывожу(echo) span id res, js его просто не видит, может я не прав, но вроде бы так)

Comment: В js, да, когда добавляю в js `document.getElementById("res").getAttribute("data-variable")‌​;` он сразу перестает работать, после нажатия на Отправить не чего не происходит, по сути потому, что он не может найти ид res

Comment: а вы еcho так и писали как тут, не забыли про `<span id=\"res\" data-variable=\"test\"></span>`
Просто только что проверил у себя, все нормально выдит js

Comment: Писал без \, попробовал ваш вариант, все равно не работает

Comment: тут я никак не помогу... может у вас js не там подключен
мой код `window.onload = function()
{
 var foo = document.getElementById("some").getAttribute('data-value');
    console.log(foo);
}
` и `<?echo "<div id=\"some\" class=\"some\" data-value=\"thisvalue\">adwdawdawdawdawd</div>";?>`
выводит в консоль thisvalue.

Comment: У вас js и php находятся в 1 файле?

Comment: Нет, в отдельных

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.